# Why can't I see all of the client certificates available when I visit my web site locally on Windows 7 IIS 7?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, certificate, internet-explorer

My team has recently moved to Windows 7 for our developer machines. We are attempting to configure IIS for application testing. Our application requires SSL and client certificates in order to authenticate.

**What I've done:**

- I have configured IIS to require SSL and require (and tried accept) certificates under SSL Settings.
- I have created the https binding and set it to the proper server certificate.
- I've installed all the root and intermediate chain certificates for the soft certificates properly in current user and local machine stores.

**The problem**

When I browse to the web site, the SSL connection is established and I am prompted to choose a certificate. The issue is that the certificate is one that is created by my company that would be invalid for use in the application. I am not given the soft certificates that I have installed using MMC and IE.

We are able to utilize the soft certs from our development machines to our Windows 2008 servers that host the application.

**What I did:**

- I have attempted to copy the Root CA to every folder location for the Current User and Location Machine account stores that the company certificate's root is in.

**My questions:**

- Could I be mishandling the certs anywhere else?
- Could there be a local/group policy that could be blocking the other certs from use?
- What (if anything) should have to be done differently on Windows 7 from 2008 in regards to IIS?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I dont have an answer, but I would like all the drive by,  shit question asking folks to take note of how it should be done.

Comment: @Jay. This is a great question. Thanks for adding good content to the community here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to some external security policies that renew each week. Recreated the above process with a PC not on the network and it worked fine. Thanks overzealous security administrators!